# What is the use of eigenvalue problems?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am really stuck with the eigenvalue problem. Is there an alternative way to solve $Ax=b$ where we have $A$ and $b$ and was used to get $x$ by inverse or iterations?, Or it is for a different type of problems (dynamic ones which I read) where it has the form $Ax=y$ and you don't know both $x$ and $y$ so you make it $Ax=\lambda x$

More specific, if it is alternative to solve $Ax=b$, the regular problem, can any one show me how this can be done with very simple illustration please.
Thanks a lot

Comment: There are an abundance of different decomposition methods used to solve such a problem. LU, SVD and QR decompositions to name just a few.

Comment: @MBM: Is it fair to say that you want to know an answer to the question "Why do I care about solutions to $Ax=\lambda x$?" Are you trying to ask something more specific?

Comment: @EricStucky: Thanks for replying. I mean my question. Is eigenvalues  just a method from many methods used to solve Ax=b as Mattos said. If yes, where b has gone, as I say Ax=lmda x, not b anymore?. OR it is not an alternative method but solution to particular set of problems (e.g.: dynamic ones) that has form Ax=lmda x, not Ax=b.

Comment: [This one](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40454/practical-applications-of-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors) was a past discussion on the practical relevance of eigenvalues problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalue problem $Ax=\lambda x$ can be thought of as a special case of the "standard problem", by left-multiplying both sides by the identity: $IAx = I(\lambda x)$ and simplifying to $Ax=\lambda Ix$ and finally
$$(A-\lambda I)x=0$$

So you see that this is $Ax=b$ where $A$ has been replaced with $A-\lambda I$ and $b=0$, and this is good for computational purposes.

But it is not conceptually kosher because the $\lambda$ is a variable too, and so your matrix now contains a variable. It is probably more useful to think about it as a completely different sort of problem. In particular: the most important output of $Ax=b$ gives information about $x$, but the most important output of $Ax=\lambda x$ gives information about $A$.